# How to read data from file containing variables

Tags: bash

I have a bash script for initializing iptables.

```
#!/bin/sh

EXTIF="eth0"
INTIF="eth1"

INTIP="192.168.0.1/32"
EXTIP=$(/sbin/ip addr show dev "$EXTIF" | perl -lne 'if(/inet (\S+)/){print$1;last}');

UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"
INTNET="192.168.0.1/24"

/sbin/iptables-restore -v < iptables.rules
```

I have `iptables.rules` file containing something like this:

```
-A OUTPUT -o $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $INTNET -j REJECT
```

How can I pass those variables from bash script to `iptables.rules` or evaluate them?

Comment: Cross-posted from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289665/use-external-file-with-variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
while read line; do eval "echo ${line}"; done < iptables.rules | /sbin/iptables-restore -v
```

or more nicely formatted:

```
while read line
  do eval "echo ${line}"
done < iptables.rules | /sbin/iptables-restore -v
```

This forces the variable expansion stuff.  You definitely need to be sure you understand what's in those variables; I suspect that if somebody could set a variable to an arbitrary value they could use it to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: This works well for me

Answer (score 1):

I would not want to trust this in general execution without a *lot* of content tests, at which point it becomes easier to feed it through a macro processor instead of trying to substitute shell variables into it.  I *strongly* recommend going that way instead.  That said, something like this should work:

```
f="$(mktemp)" || exit 1
{echo '/sbin/iptables-restore <<__EOF'; cat iptables.rules; echo '__EOF'} >"$f"
. "$f"
rm "$f"
```

Comment: In Bash (note that the question is tagged `[bash]`, but the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`), you can source something on the fly without a temporary file: `source <(echo '...'; echo "$(<iptables.rules)"; echo '...')`

Answer (score 0):

If `iptables.rules` contains:

```
RULES="-A OUTPUT -o $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $INTNET -j REJECT"
```

And your script sources that file, then the variables will be evaluated.

```
#!/bin/sh

EXTIF="eth0"
INTIF="eth1"

INTIP="192.168.0.1/32"
EXTIP=$(/sbin/ip addr show dev "$EXTIF" | perl -lne 'if(/inet (\S+)/){print$1;last}');

UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"
INTNET="192.168.0.1/24"
. iptables.rules

/sbin/iptables-restore -v < $RULES
```

Comment: no, unfortunately...

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway:  `$RULES` isn't the name of a file.  `echo "$RULES" | /sbin/iptables-restore -v` would work if `iptables.rules` were set up correctly.